# Elasticsearch update document without creating new index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I have many existing indices partition by date. Eg: index_190901, index_190902,...

And I have an API which takes `index_name` and `doc_id` as inputs. User want to update some documents in index by input `fields`, `index_name`, `doc_id`.

I'm trying to update document using the following code:

```
        updateRequest.index("invalid_daily_index")
          .type("type")
          .id("id")
          .doc(jsonMap)
```

It works fine if user input existing index but if user input non-existing index, new index with no document will be created.

I know that I can setup [auto_create_index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation) but I still want to create index automatically when I insert new documents.

Check if index is existed with `client.indices.exists(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)` is quite expensive. I don't want to check it every request

How to make Elasticsearch to not create new index when I use `updateRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

You can block the option to automaticaly create non existing indices by putting `false` to the `action.auto_create_index` setting of the cluster

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : { "action.auto_create_index” : "false" }
}
```

For details take a look at the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation)

Comment: But I want to auto create index when I insert